# Windows Store - Everything runs on 'Worker Thread'

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Very simple question: why does a button click and even work scheduled via `Dispatcher.RunAsync` execute on a thread named 'Worker Thread'?

Is this actually just the UI thread but someone forgot to name it correctly?

Comment: Async methods run on worker threads. I believe Dispather.RunAsync actually creates a worker thread which delegates the action it's taking back to the UI Thread. I'm not sure if the UI Thread itself has the name Worker Thread, but I believe in either respect (from my limited testing), that a new task is created regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike Taulty blogs about it, although I can't find a technical explanation.

http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2012/08/30/windows-8-development-when-your-ui-thread-is-not-your-main-thread.aspx